# JQuery AJAX Post and Refresh Page Content without reload page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, wordpress

Now I know that I am at risk here of asking a duplicate question, however I don't really know what to search for because I am a complete AJAX jQuery noob. Believe me, I have tried searching what I think is the obvious, with no luck so please go easy on me.

I have a php wordpress site which shows prices in GBP as default. At the top, is a select box with `onchange="this.form.submit()"` which allows the user to change the default currency that all prices are quoted in.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select name="ChangeCurrency" onChange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

On the home page, are several, what I call **"shortcode widgets"**, each one containing products and price tables. A dashboard if you like.

How it currently works (inefficient):

1. User changes select.
2. Form submitted
3. Homepage reloaded with updated prices in selected currency.

This is not good, because whenever somebody changes currency, the whole page is reloaded (this takes time, transfers approx 1mb without caching, not to mention unnecessary load on the server).

What I want (more efficient):

1. When the select box is changed, I wish to asynchronously post the form which changes the currency session variable.
2. Each "shortcode widget" is updated one by one without having to reload the entire page.

Is this something that jquery can do? where do I start?

Just in case it makes any difference so that you can see what I mean, here is the URL so that you can see what I am talking about... http://bit.ly/10ChZys

**PART 2:**
I have used jQuery and ajax to update the fixTable thanks to a mashup of answers below... I am using session variables to store the users choice, that way, if they return to the site, the option will be saved.

I am having problems with my code because the session variable stored within http://goldealers.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/gd/tables.php?currency=GBP&table=fixTable appears to have a different session_id to the user's session id because the option is no longer stored.

Is there a way of telling the server that they are one and the same session?

**SOLUTION**
I used Ribot's Solution to start with which worked and solved the initial problem, then extended with NomikOS's solution...

Comment: How may products which needs prices currency do you have on page?

Comment: It is tabular product pricing. There are about 7 tables (shortcode widgets), each with approximately 14 prices which need to change. Prices are currently calculated in php when loading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, jQuery can do it using ajax.

First of all, when using ajax, you don't have to post a form to get the data. Ajax in jQuery will load the text data of an url.

You may start by giving your select an id (here id="changeCurrency") and:

```
$("#changeCurrency").change(function(){
    currency = $('#changeCurrency option:selected').val() // get the selected option's value
    $("#some_div").load("someurl.php?currency=" + currency);
});
```

Now read up on jQuery and ajax for what kind of ajax call you need to do that suites your needs the best.

Comment: Why use `$('#changeCurrency option:selected').val()` when you can use `$(this).val()`?

Comment: Each of my shortcode widgets are generated in functions. is it possible to get jquery to get a php script to call the function and generate the html (replacing the entire div content) with the contents of the returned html data from the php function?

Comment: Gravy: yes, if your php function can output only your needed html on page url.php, and the div has id="div_id", you can do $("#div_id").load("url.php")

Comment: popnoodles: suppose someone doesn't like to use "this" for wanting to be more articulate?

Comment: I think i like this method. It seems most simple and elegant a solution. For each of the dashboard widgets, I will inject html to replace the existing tables from my shortcode functions. I will give this a try and let you all know how it goes. I may come back to you with more questions over the next few days... Thanks. :)

Comment: you're welcome, and please select the correct answer to your question :)

Comment: @gravy you need to know much more about send AJAX to server. `load()` needs more config. take a look to my answer too (yes, the long and bored one :)) to complement this....

Comment: Don't worry, I will do.. I have already seen something of yours which I really like... :)

Comment: @gravy great, I just put some order in the code, still you need to know some other things but this is a great start. don't forget give us some credit with a nice upvote to every one. ;)

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: this answer show some ideas about the php backend for the AJAX process. It is a complement for the other answers talking about the frontend process.

1.-  a mockup to manage AJAX request in WP, just some ideas, ok?

```
add_action('init', 'process_ajax_callback');

function process_ajax_callback()
{
    if ( ! $_REQUEST['go_ajax'])
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['nonce_my_ajax']))
        {
            $nonce   = $_REQUEST['nonce_my_ajax'];
            if ( ! wp_verify_nonce($nonce    = $_REQUEST['nonce_my_ajax'], 'nonce_my_ajax'))
            {
                throw new Exception("Nonce token invalid."); // security
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $output['result']    = false;
        $output['message']   = $e->getMessage();

        echo json_encode($output);
        exit;
    }

    $result  = true;
    $message = '';

    switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
    {
        case 'update_price':
        try
        {
            // update price
            // price value comes in $_REQUEST['price']
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $result              = false;
            $message             = $e->getMessage();
        }
        break;      

        case 'other_actions':
        break;      
    }

    $output['result']    = $result ? true : false;
    $output['message']   = $message;

    echo json_encode($output);
    exit;
}
```

2.- don't forget security

```
// nonce_my_ajax is passed to javascript like this:
wp_localize_script('my_js_admin', 'myJsVars', array(
    'nonce_my_ajax'  => wp_create_nonce('nonce_my_ajax')
));
```

3.- in general the needed in the frontend (to use with the backend mockup showed above) is something like:

```
$("select[name='ChangeCurrency']").live("change", function() {
    var price = $(this).val();
    $.post(
            window.location.href,
            {
                go_ajax : 1, // parse ajax
                action : 'update_price', // what to do
                price : price, // vars to use in backend
                nonce_my_ajax : myJsVars.nonce_my_ajax // security
            },
            function(output) {
            if ( output.result == true )
                // update widgets or whatever
                // $("#my_div").html("we happy, yabadabadoo!");
                // or do nothing (AJAX action was successful)
            else
                alert(output.message)
            }, 'json');
});
```

4.- You can use `$.get()` or `$.post()` to send/process data to/in server but `.load()` is not good when you update DB because you can't manage returning messages of failures with the precision of a `json` response (for example: multiples validation error messages). Just use `.load()` to load HTML views.

**UPDATE:**

Set `session_id()` where can be executed both for normal requests and for ajax requests and at the early stage as possible. I hope you are using a class to wrap your plugin, if not now is the right moment to do it... example:

```
class my_plugin {

    function __construct()
    {
        if ( ! session_id())
        {
            session_start();
        }

        add_action('init', array($this, 'process_ajax_callback'));

        // ...
    }   

    function process_ajax_callback()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

About nonce based security:

> A security feature available in WordPress is a “nonce”. Generally, a
>   “nonce” is a token that can only be used once and are often used to
>   prevent unauthorised people  from submitting data on behalf of another
>   person.
>
> Ref: http://myatus.com/p/wordpress-caching-and-nonce-lifespan/

In this mockup `nonce_my_ajax` is just an example, indeed it should be more unique like `nonce_{my_plugin_name}`, or even better `nonce_{my_plugin_name}_{what_action}` where `what_action` represents `updating user`, or `inserting new book`, etc...

More info about it: [WP Codex: WordPress Nonces](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces), [WPtuts+: Capabilities and Nonces](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/capabilities-and-nonces/).

Comment: Hi there NomikOS. Are you able to help me with this nonce business??? Will this help protect against for example json scraping???

Comment: @gravy Hi, answer updated... This last issue `nonces` is going out of scope related to the title of your question. SO people likes `1Q=1A` style. Don't hesitate in open a new question. HNY mate.

Answer (score -1):

Drop the onchange and add an ID

```
<select name="ChangeCurrency" id="ChangeCurrency">...
```

On the page give all your prices a price in your base currency as well as outputting them

```
<span class="price" data-base="0.12">&pound;0.12</span>
```

In your JS have a conversion table

```
// base currency is GBP
// each currency has 0: currency symbol, 1: conversion rate
var currency={"GBP":["&pound;", 1], "USD":["&dollar;", 0.67]};
var usercurrency=currency['GBP'];
```

and bind an event to the change

```
$('#ChangeCurrency').on('change', function(){
    // post to the server to update it
    $.post(...);
    // set locally on the page
    usercurrency=currency[$(this).val()];
    // and change all the values
    $('.price').each(function(){
        $(this).html(usercurrency[0] + (usercurrency[1] * $(this).data('base')).toFixed(2) );
    });
}).trigger('change'); // trigger this to run on page load if you want.
```

I haven't checked any of this code

Comment: Hi there, thanks. I will look into this however your method has me worried about the js being degradeable... If the user does not have js, or js is turned off, how do I still allow the user to submit the form to change the currency using your method? I know in my above example, I have onchange="this.form.submit()" but this doesnt stop me from adding a button saying "submit".

Comment: If there is no JS the event I wrote out won't be caught and when they press submit everything works as you expect.